# Burninate [adobe-stock]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, burnination

There is [exactly one question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87447/what-is-the-difference-between-an-enhanced-and-an-extended-adobe-stock-image-lic) with the [adobe-stock](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-stock) tag and I don't see the use it has to be different from [stock-images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-images).

Please get Trogdor. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Re-tagged to [stock-images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-images)...it should be deleted on its own in a day or so. Thank you!